# How efficient is the EOSIO software for distributed locking, relative to other database software?

Tags: eosio-code, database, data-storage

I am researching the best software for distributed locking purposes, and came across this article: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html

> I think the Redlock algorithm is a poor choice because it is “neither fish nor fowl”: it is unnecessarily heavyweight and expensive for efficiency-optimization locks, but it is not sufficiently safe for situations in which correctness depends on the lock.

I am looking for a database with guaranteed "correctness." I believe EOSIO has this feature, but I am wondering how it compares to current distributed locking mechanisms performance-wise. To be clear, I am referring to spinning up an independent instance of the EOSIO software, not an application on the public EOS chain. Thanks!

Comment: When you say performance-wise, what metrics are you specifically referring to?

Comment: Specifically, I am interested in maintaining low latency under high db transaction load. Memory is less important.